# Euro sign not showing up right in HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, euro

I have a page on my site with a form for editing event information and Updating it to the database. I have a select box with options for Admission Price, which are all preceded by a euro sign in my HTML code, but are showing up as �1 on the webpage. I have the exact same Admission Price select input on other pages with identical code and they work fine, can someone help please??

```
<p class='form_box_text'>Admission:
  <select name='admission' id=''>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='Free' "; if($admission=='Free') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">Free</option>
    <option value='€1' "; if($admission=='€1') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€1</option>
    <option value='€2' "; if($admission=='€2') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€2</option>
    <option value='€3' "; if($admission=='€3') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€3</option>
    <option value='€4' "; if($admission=='€4') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€4</option>
    <option value='€5' "; if($admission=='€5') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€5</option>
    <option value='€6' "; if($admission=='€6') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€6</option>
    <option value='€7' "; if($admission=='€7') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€7</option>
    <option value='€8' "; if($admission=='€8') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€8</option>
    <option value='€9' "; if($admission=='€9') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€9</option>
    <option value='€10' "; if($admission=='€10') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€10</option>
    <option value='€11' "; if($admission=='€11') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€11</option>
    <option value='€12' "; if($admission=='€12') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€12</option>
    <option value='€13' "; if($admission=='€13') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€13</option>
    <option value='€14' "; if($admission=='€14') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€14</option>
    <option value='€15' "; if($admission=='€15') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€15</option>
    <option value='€16' "; if($admission=='€16') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€16</option>
    <option value='€17' "; if($admission=='€17') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€17</option>
    <option value='€18' "; if($admission=='€18') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€18</option>
    <option value='€19' "; if($admission=='€19') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€19</option>
    <option value='€20' "; if($admission=='€20') echo("selected=\ "selected\" "); echo ">€20</option>
  </select><span id='required'>*</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the encoding, but without a sample it is hard to evaluate...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try replacing the euro sign with `&euro;`: €

Comment: If you don't know how to show code in the answers, it might be worth taking a look at the [markdown editing](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) pages.

Comment: @David Thomas I was actually about to edit and was surprised to see the work done. Thanks!

Comment: You're absolutely welcome! (sorry if I stepped on your toes, though...) =)

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo "&euro;'"; ?>
```

or

```
<p> &euro; </p>
```

or

```
<p> &#8364;</p>
```

or

```
<p>&#8364;</p>
```

will work

Answer (score 3):

There are three different techniques you could use to show the euro sign :

```
&euro;
&#8364;
&#x20AC;
```

See [this PAGE](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/euro.html) for more reference

Comment: ok so how are these encoded into the database? its just strange becuase the euro sign works perfectly on the other pages that i copied the code from